# Как лучше задокументировать массив массивов массивов при помощи JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

У меня имеется следующая структура данных. Типы элементов корневого массива фиксированы. Как лучше задокументировать такую структуру при помощи JSDoc?

```
[
    [
        ['aqua-160', 160, 'PreCleaning'],
        ['aqua-260', 260, 'PreCleaning']
    ],
    [
        ['aqua-360', 360, 'PostCleaning']
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как на счет [@typedef](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html)?

```js
@typedef DataArray
@type {array}
@property {string} 0 - attribute name.
@property {number} 1 - value to set.
@property {string} 2 - comment

@typedef DataGroup
@type {array}
@property {DataArray} 0 - data

@typedef Collection
@type {array}
@property {DataGroup} 0 - data
```

Примерно так. Только названия лучше подобрать